# People who are interested and some what experts of history and maybe tech, what would you do in this very isekai situation?

Tags: science-based, magic, technology, warfare, technological-development

In this impossible hypothetical situation, let's say through some supernatural means, you are transported to the royal palace of a rather small but rich kingdom that are rich in resources/raw materials such as iron, copper, zinc, nickel, molybdenum, lead,manganese, gold, platinum, marble, gravel, wood, food, sulfric acid from hot springs, salt petre from bat caves, etc.., basically, its very abundant. In front of you is the king who summoned you here. He used an extremely dangerous once in a life time secret magic with a very long incantation that only their blood line has, to get help from the Gods by sending them a champion from another world to help them, but instead they sent you just for the sake of the God's pleasure. Confused, you look around only to see that the king is begging for your assistance on the matter of helping this nation out. Soon, the king makes clear his intentions for summoning a champion from the Gods, they are getting invaded within a few months. An arrogant and ruthless but very powerful, well known, and feared, imperialistic colonialist nation has sent an “ambassador" to give them an ultimatum that they hand over the kingdom in the next 2 months without resistance or they will mercilessly invade it within the next 5 months, which is the least amount of time they need in order to mobilize their armies. This army consists of legions of wyverns and a few but powerful dragons, a few mighty powerful warriors that can strengthen their physical capabilities beyond that of humans, organized platoons of mages, thousands of horse cavalry, and most importantly, 500,000 normal infantryman as their total military strength, not to mention they have the resources and economy to back it up, they are really just expansionist imperials. They have heard that this nation has lots of resources and, for whatever reason, they believe that securing this area's resources will help them expand their already large influence even more. And they seem to not want a compromise short of capturing the entire nation.

This small kingdom that you got summoned in is a relatively mountainous inland nation, with no navy aside from trade boats and galleons that go through them in the great central river of commerce which is one of their greatest trade routes. This kingdom only has a total population of 250,000 people, and only 30,000 are active military personnel. They mostly consist of infantry and archer divisions, but they do have a few hundred mages, a few wyvern cavalries, and a few hundred horse cavalry as their total military power. You later learn that while they maybe rich in resources and have good trade routes with other nations and even probably an alliance, they have became a bit too complacent and relied on them for a bit too much as they didn't expect to experience such an invading force to come to them. It seems that they have turned their backs on this small kingdom after they heard who the invading force was as they also do seem to fear this powerful colonialist Empire and would rather not get their ire or some other reason that would let this empire direct their anger towards them, so they choose to cut all their connections with this small, and rich kingdom.

Left with no choice lest the king gives up his kingdom to the invaders and him possibly executed, he calls upon his final trump card and asks the Gods to summon a champion, of which they responded disappointingly by sending you instead of an almighty being with overwhelming power.

Now, while you were summoned by this king, you received a special magic called telekinetic structural editor. You will be able to magically shape inorganic materials to your will. Meaning, if you use the power to extract all the iron from this ore without impurities, you will get a block of pure iron. If you want to put carbon content to make steel, you can get the surrounding carbon from coal and add in equal proportions the right amount to make steel. Heck, you can even imagine it to shape itself into a cannon, or even intricate little tools like lathes and drills, or even small parts of guns life precise rifling.

Now that you know your powers and the very dire situation about this kingdom, what will you do and create in order for this nation to stand against it's invaders and protect yourself too, while improving their technology too?

(Also, lets just assume these mages are the typical fire ball throwing dudes, some are specialized in other elements more than the other like water mages, healers, some are of higher rank, etc. and also the wyverns are similar to the pteranodons in Jurassic park and Dragons are the equivalent of flying, fire breathing/Ice breathing/poison breathing t-rexes, which are roughly equivalent to 500 men, a number I pulled out of my ass.)

Comment: Hi New Person!  Just so you're aware, WB.SE is (sadly) not a general discussion, story writing or opinion seeking kind of Q&A site. You might be wise to take a look at the [tour] and [help] to see what kinds of questions we field here and also find out [what WB.SE is all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about). It looks like you might have an interesting world & setting! Perhaps we'll be able to help out with some other problems or issues your worldbuilding is facing!

Comment: Oh okay then thanks!

Comment: @elemtilas Beat me to it. The many issues here are compounded by no specifications of what mages can do nor dragons or wyverns or what wyverns are in your world. No indication of geography, not much by way of historical context either. Story writing we don't do, addressing single, specific, constrained and well defined problems to be solved - that we can help you with.

Comment: I would say it's a valid and specific question (formulating a war plan) and one can make assumptions about what generic mages, dragons, etc. are capable of.  (Isekai universes are nothing if not formulaic.)   The one question that needs to be asked is whether the "hero" also has the knowledge to shape specific modern things, without knowing how they work.  After all, the average person doesn't know what a cannon looks like, or the formula for black gunpowder, or how a drill bit is made and so wouldn't be able to make them even with the given power.

Comment: Yes, thats why I asked it exactly in this site. From some of the answers that I've seen in my short experience in this place, I'm sure plenty of people have experience with dealing these sorts of things. Also, lets just assume these mages are the typical fire ball throwing dudes, some are specialized in other elements more than the other, some are of higher rank, etc. and also the wyverns are similar to the pteranodons in Jurassic park and Dragons are the equivalent of flying, fire breathing/Ice breathing/poison breathing t-rexes, which are roughly equivalent to 1000 men.

Comment: In real history, the small kingdom is history. In a fantasy story, *anything* can happen. And I really mean anything. The question places almost no constraints on the plot, so much that the only limit is the author's capacity of invention. And, by the way, 30,000 full-time soldiers (if that's what "military personnel" means) at a population of 250,000 is simply impossible -- it would mean that for every two men of arms-bearing age one is in the army, not contributing to the economy; that's a higher proportion that even National-Socialist Germany could afford at the end of WW2.

Comment: I see... I just wanted to see what others would do in such extreme odds. I'm sorry if I answered stupid things I'm pretty new here and just thought of this situation.

Comment: Welcome to WB.SE! Great name btw. While i don't have an answer per se, I recommend you take a look at "The Rising of the Shield Hero". Has a similar (not equal i believe) plot to yours and it might give you some ideas.

Comment: Haha, that was actually one of the isekai anime that I have watched along with many others like GATE and Overlord, that gave me inspirations to write stuff down.

Comment: I totally get your desire to see what others here would do in a situation like this. And to be honest, if you'd asked this kind of "opinion based" question on any other worldbuilding forum, no one would bat an eyelash!  It's just that in this particular forum (Stack Exchange) there are a couple rules given from on high that we really do try to adhere to.  If you could edit your question so that it reads more like "what could this character reasonably do given X, Y & Z criteria that are the nature of the world and given M, N & O that are nature of the person", then it would conform...

Comment: (cont)... a little better to the way questions here should be worded.  Like I said before -- interesting proposition, your question writing skills just need to be honed in this place!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

5 months of manufacturing by a single person will be insufficient to provide enough weaponry to offset an over 15:1 disadvantage in troops.  Nor is that span long enough to train others to do manufacturing or long enough to train the troops the hero has with new weapons even if they had them instantly.  Moreover, it's unspecified whether the hero has the knowledge to make modern weapons anyway or the training to operate them, even if they have the ability to edit them into existence, so presumably they don't.

*The hero cannot allow the enemy army to even begin assembling or it's game over.*  The hero is going to have to be utterly brutal: strike first, without provocation, and commit to [total war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_war) which means that civilians are legitimate military targets and there are no restrictions on the tactics or weapons used.  By modern rules of war, this would be considered a war crime but total war was the norm in the medieval era so the king and his army won't be bothered by it.

The hero will create small clusters of fire bombs (oil, magnesium, phosphorous, thermite; all sorts of creative possibilities exist.) and drop them using wyverns in a first strike against the enemy's largest cities, preferably in the dead of night to gain the element of surprise.  Population centers of that era are very [flammable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_town_and_city_fires) and even if water mages are present to put out fires in the cities, enough fires burning simultaneously will overwhelm them and cause the city to be leveled.  Continue this firebombing campaign unrelentingly to utterly destroy as many population centers as possible until the enemy empire no longer has the means to make war.

By now, the enemy armies will begin rallying and firebombs will not be much help against a moving and alert army or enemy fortifications.  This brings us to the even less pleasant way the hero will deal with them: [gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_weapons_in_World_War_I).  Extracting chlorine from salt will yield containers of chlorine gas.  Using wyverns/mages to drop them into an enemy formation and detonating them using a fireball from the mages will yield a cloud of chlorine gas whose effects are too terrible to be described.  Positioning of friendly units is crucial; nobody is going to want to be downwind of where the chlorine is.

Ultimately, the goal is stave off enemy armies while trying to destroy enough cities that their nation collapses.  As they say, war is hell.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thank you for sharing your insight on this, by the way, what i meant by the hero was what if YOU (The reader) was the one transported, thats what I meant. I just wanted to find different and great answers to know what would they do personally, and select the one I think is the best to base my story on. Thanks for answering. Also, btw besides from striking first, what if you failed on that and destroyed a lot of their logistics, but they still have like a lot of military might left and fended you off. If they ever drew near the city, would you resort to guerilla warfare?

Comment: @TheDingusLord  Not sure what you're asking?  Logistics is **everything**; with a lot of their logistics destroyed, the empire can't feed or arm their armies and they start falling apart fast and disintegrate long before they reach the king's border.  This hopefully brings the force ratio down near 1:1, giving the king's army a hopefully winnable defensive campaign and buying breathing room for the hero to come up with more dirty tricks and train more of the king's army.

Comment: @TheDingusLord  Addendum: if the empire has any sense, they won't even try to continue the invasion.  They need the armies they can feed to maintain order and protect the population from the disintegrated armies they couldn't feed, which will start looting and pillaging inside the empire because they're starving.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I need to clarify and make a more reasonable situation. Let's say your first few night attacks were successful, but later they realized that the situation need to be dealt with immediately and sent in a powerful and well equipped platoon of wyvern knights and fended you off so you were forced to retreat back to home base. What do you do now?

Comment: @TheDingusLord  Gas bomb their wyvern bases as part of the first strike, use mages to boost the strength of the friendly wyverns to overcome the enemy, have the hero produce firearms and ambush the enemy wyvern knights with them, switch to single-wyvern stealth missions where slow fuse based firebombs are emplaced instead, etc.  Also, the disadvantage of the empire is that it's big and can't protect everything: switch to attacking smaller population centers randomly or get the mages to provide teleportation to get the wyverns to pop. centers away from where the enemy can intercept them.

Comment: Ah I see.. thanks for answering! Nice, I forgot about teleportation lol, though I think it would be very costly and limited to do teleportation. Also I'm sorry if I said some stupid things earlier, I'm not exactly the sharpest tool in the shed and I'm also new here and just thought of the situation.

Answer (score 2):

### The big problem is that anything you do, they can throw numbers at you.

If you try to send assassins to burn their cities, they can just mass water mages and kill your assassins, or use massed wyverns to ambush your people. There's lots of ways they can counter any scheme you use, and they know their country better than you, so they can counter any aggressive moves. As such, you need game changers.

### Do spy checks and see if you can get any support.

Does the enemy have spies in your city reporting on your every advance and plan? If so, any plan you make could easily be countered.

There is a common set of things to look out for when finding spies. MICE and RASCLs. Money, Ideology, Coercion, Ego. Look for people who suddenly have an unusual increase in wealth like fancy new houses or jewelry, who have a compromising and dangerous ideology from the empire or their allies, who have secrets like cheating, drug use, or violations of heteronormativity.

Anyone who has had some major slight against them is also suspect. Passed over for a promotion, humiliated in some fashion. People have lots of reasons to turn.

Unless the person is in an extremely sensitive place it's best to leave spies in place. They can be used to feed your enemy false information to weaken their responses. Remember that too much false information and the enemy will consider the spy burnt. It's best to save serious misinformation for major offenses. Build up their credibility with minor victories, then burn that credibility to mass kill the enemy.

### Mass produce guns and cannons, and arm everyone.

Women, children, the elderly, injured. If they can hold a gun, they can fight. Train them to do focused fire at a particular point so they can fire at massed troops, or focus fire on dragons.

The more firepower you have the better chance you have to withstand a heavy chance.

Get trusted smiths who have no chance of being spies and whose family and friends aren't likely to be spies, and get them to produce as many weapons as possible.

These troops will be useless out in the open, but they can defend fixed positions.

### Do diplomacy.

Are there any factions within the enemy that might turn against them? Are there any mercenaries you can hire? Can you turn any allies back to you with shows of wealth? Seek out any avenue to help yourself. If you can funnel some money to a racial minority in the empire and cause a rebellion you might buy yourself a few months.

Also, consider- why not surrender? Talk to your diplomats about this. Can you extend peace and surrender talks out so that they don't mobilize their armies as quickly. If you're really lucky and they're stupid they'll send a key general or their king or such over, and you can kill them or take them hostage.

They say resistance is forbidden, but this is an immensely expensive affair they are doing. Everyone is willing to negotiate for the right price. If the rival empire refuses to negotiate then their subordinates will wonder why their leader is throwing away their lives over some petty concessions, and their morale will be weakened.

### Make your country a slog.

Bombs, machine gun turrets, poison gas attacks, poisoned well and food, hidden railway lines to quickly move resources. Do everything you can to make every inch hell to take. You want them to attack a point, make them pay in blood for it, and fade away.

### Cultivate your own spies.

For making spies there's a different acronym. RASCLs.

Reciprocation, Authority, Scarcity, Commitment/Consistency, Liking, Social Proof.

You need to give people minor gifts, show them that you have the authority to get them what they want, be a reliable ally, be friendly and nice, and prove yourself with other contacts. Spies recruited under MICE are fragile and erratic, and often break.

But someone who trusts you to help their empire? Perhaps to stop an over ambitious king who is leading their people into a suicidal charge to help their own ego? They can make a solid spy.

You can even help their career, by providing them with blackmail material on their rivals within the enemy to prove that their (actually loyal) colleagues are spies.

Be careful about burning your spies. Only burn them for a big score, like killing a major leader of the enemy.

### Kill the rich and powerful.

Nobles and medievail societies often didn't have a good concept of how to protect their elites. Nobles are vital for society, in that they can organize and lead people around. Empires are hard but fragile- without their leaders they shatter.

Find the people giving orders, or with the fanciest armor. Kill them, and the rest will fall.

### Conquer the rest of the world.

Your allies refused to help you. Fuck them. They're next.

### How power struggles work.

In the empire or the kingdom, there are powerful people. Nobles, skilled scientists, priests, charismatic peasants, archmages, elite dragons, whatever.

The empire ones have been promised land, titles, and money to help in the conquering of the kingdom- no ruler can rule alone, they need people, and those people demand a cut of the loot.

But there are always people who lose out. Someone needs to serve on the frontline, and they'll lose more troops than others. A title of duke or head engineer going to one person means another person doesn't get it.

The king people the empire has been subverted have been promised power. The empire likely has promised some of the lords of your kingdom or people of power they can retain power when the empire rules, so long as they deliver lots of resources under them.

There's also a complex web of friendships, rivalries, loves, marriages, debts, and complex feelings that criss cross across both lands, complicating things.

If you don't know what's happening half of your soldiers might abandon the fight when they come to you. If you do know what's happening you might convince the empire to fight among itself.

### Here's an example.

The empire recently conquered an orc like species. They're violent, tribalistic, and fast breeding. The empire has decided that they will serve best as shock troopers. Any tricks or traps left by you can be absorbed by the orcs.

This works because the empire's leader has a close friendship with the orc chieftan. They've promised them great glory and personal advancement if they commit their people to a suicidal war. It's a win win for the empire. They support one elite, and the recently conquered orcs are weakened so they can't rebel.

If I supported a rival chieftan with weapons and intel and money and the information about the plan to sacrifice the orcs, a civil war might break out. Then, the empire would need to mobilize to put down the orcs, or the orcs might rampage across their empire while the empire tried to invade my kingdom.

Why fight your enemy when you can let your enemy fight themselves?

### How to be a ruler after?

People hate change, so ideally you always want to keep things slow.

Adopt the symbols of religion and royalty. You're already summoned by the gods. It shouldn't be that hard to claim you are a prophet of whatever gods. If you can, marry a princess to get a firm legal claim to the throne. If you can, make it so you fulfill any prophesies so you look more legitimate. With your powers and heavy bribery, it shouldn't be too hard to fit a bunch of them.

Make sure your policies are successful, but attribute publicly all success to the king. No one likes being outshined. Privately, make sure their subordinates and followers know who is actually being successful, and who got them into their shitty situation.

Then at some point, you can engineer a retirement or accidental hunting accident for the king, and take over for the good of the kingdom and for the gods. With your ability to make poisons, accidents shouldn't be that hard to encourage. If they are reasonable of course, you can leave them, but they got into this bad situation, they're probably not the smartest.

For the surrounding regions, use the speed of technology (rails, airships, steel ships with steam engines etc) and your powerful artillery to adopt a mongol like rulership of the surrounding regions.

Steam engines have been made since medieval times. They knew how to do it. They just didn't have the quality of steel to make them not explode under high pressure. You do. You can rails and steam powered boats.

If you can seize the empire, by right of conquest or religious authority, you can just outright annex them with overwhelming numbers. If not, go mongol.

You can quickly move in, demand tribute, and if they refuse bombard them with guns and artillery till they surrender. You don't have the numbers to rule everyone, but you do have the numbers to overwhelm each region with overwhelming speed and logistics. You can build up your country's wealth and prestige whilst making those around you your protectorates. You may annex some places, but mostly you'll just get them to pay for protection, which they failed to give you.

Comment: Brilliant! Thankyou for answering! Though due to my limited brain works, me trying to think of complex situations like individual spies and power struggles might burn me out but I'm prepared to research and do my best to do something with this.

Comment: Nap, also what will you do to the recently fallen empire? Will you take on the position of new ruler? Usurp the position of the king that summoned you here? Also what will you do to the allies that left you for dead? Will you colonize them once you developed enough military strength from your spoils of war? Or will you take over them and make sure you rule with an iron fist and fairly?

Comment: I added an example to help with how spies might work- in any conflict, there's always gonna be a loser who is very bitter about the place they are in. That's fertile ground for recruiting spies. 

For the fallen empire, if it's very ordered you could take on the position of ruler. It's hard holding lots of ground, when you only have 30k troops, even if they are teched up. If you can somehow convince them you are the prophet of the gods, perhaps you can seize the reigns of the empire. I edited in how I would do it.

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely do something with this.

Comment: The hero & kingdom is going to do all that in 5 months?  Improbable.  Both spy networks and cultivating diplomatic contacts takes years and years and a single hero can't mass produce anything.  The "well poisoning" idea has some promise though...if used on the enemy as part of a first strike.  Either a steady supply of water soluble heavy metal or radioactive compounds introduced into a enemy city's wells/cisterns will cause cumulative poisoning effects over time whose source will be mysterious and untraceable to the inhabitants.  For immediate effect, use hallucinogens instead.

Comment: Making a spy/diplomatic network takes years. Making a few spy/diplomatic contacts doesn't take as long. Existing people may well have contacts who they feel can be turned for the right incentives. 

Also, we don't know the scale of the hero's power. He may have enough power to do this. 

They have water mages, so they may be able to purify water. They have a lot more people than you so they can brute force things.

Also, glad to help The Dingus Lord.